# How to change the default COM settings in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port, ftdi

Is it even possible? I'm using a USB to Serial FTDI chip and it loads the Virtual COM Port driver. Every time the device is enumerated after being plugged into the computer, the configured modem signals revert to a default state, and thus when the device is opened in software, the actual hardware signals match that default state between the time the port is opened and the time the settings are changed (the settings cannot be changed prior to opening the port using the Windows API, or at least not by the standard communication resource functions).

I can't figure out if this is on FTDI's end (the driver) or Microsoft's end (asserting those signals based on some arbitrary default when the device is enumerated). From MSDN on communications resources:

> "If the device has never been opened, it is configured with the system defaults."

Anybody know how to change those system defaults?

Comment: Why is this even a problem?  The port has to be opened in order to use it.  And the port should always be configured (after opening it) before it is used by the application program, regardless of what the default setting are.

Comment: @sawdust It's is a problem because my board uses the modem signals to enable the ISP of the microcontroller. This is used by third party programming tools like FlashMagic as a standard means of programming boards. I can modify the hardware such that the ISP is not inadvertently activated by the short pulses, but I will always be board-reset and it should not be the case that opening the COM port for the first time in software resets the board.